# docker-compose can't found nvidia dirver

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nvidia, nvidia-docker

I am trying to run the [clara train example](https://github.com/NVIDIA/clara-train-examples/tree/master/PyTorch/NoteBooks), but when I execute the [startClaraTrainNoteBooks.sh](https://github.com/NVIDIA/clara-train-examples/blob/master/PyTorch/NoteBooks/scripts/startClaraTrainNoteBooks.sh), the container cannot find the nvidia driver.
I already know that the script executes [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/NVIDIA/clara-train-examples/blob/master/PyTorch/NoteBooks/scripts/docker-compose.yml). So I tested whether `docker-compose` can found the nvidia driver:

```
services:
  test:
    image: nvidia/cuda:10.2-base
    command: nvidia-smi
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
          - driver: nvidia
            capabilities: [gpu]
            device_ids: ['0']
```

Output:

```
USER@test:~$ docker-compose up
WARNING: Found orphan containers (hp_nvsmi_1) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
Starting hp_test_1 ... done
Attaching to hp_test_1
test_1  | Mon Jun  7 09:01:44 2021
test_1  | +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
test_1  | | NVIDIA-SMI 460.27.04    Driver Version: 460.27.04    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
test_1  | |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
test_1  | | GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
test_1  | | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
test_1  | |                               |                      |               MIG M. |
test_1  | |===============================+======================+======================|
test_1  | |   0  GeForce RTX 206...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
test_1  | |  0%   34C    P8    17W / 215W |    100MiB /  7979MiB |      0%      Default |
test_1  | |                               |                      |                  N/A |
test_1  | +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
test_1  |
test_1  | +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
test_1  | | Processes:                                                                  |
test_1  | |  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
test_1  | |        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
test_1  | |=============================================================================|
test_1  | +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
hp_test_1 exited with code 0
```

But the `startClaraTrainNoteBooks.sh` cna not find it.

```
root@claratrain:/claraDevDay# nvidia-smi 
root@claratrain:/claraDevDay#
```

Actually, [startDocker.sh](https://github.com/NVIDIA/clara-train-examples/blob/master/PyTorch/NoteBooks/scripts/startDocker.sh) can find the driver.

```
root@c7c2d5597eb8:/claraDevDay# nvidia-smi 
Mon Jun  7 09:11:43 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.27.04    Driver Version: 460.27.04    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 206...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   35C    P8    17W / 215W |    100MiB /  7979MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
root@c7c2d5597eb8:/claraDevDay#
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `docker-compose.yml` script need to rewrite like this and working:

```
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0

version: "3.8"
services:
  claratrain:
    container_name: claradevday-pt
    hostname: claratrain
    ##### use vanilla clara train docker
    #image: nvcr.io/nvidia/clara-train-sdk:v4.0
    ##### to build image with GPU dashboard inside jupyter lab
    build:
      context: ./dockerWGPUDashboardPlugin/    # Project root
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile                 # Relative to context
    image: clara-train-nvdashboard:v4.0
    depends_on:
      - tritonserver
    ports:
      - "3030:8888"  # Jupyter lab port
      - "3031:5000"  # AIAA port
    ipc: host
    volumes:
      - ${TRAIN_DEV_DAY_ROOT}:/claraDevDay/
      - /raid/users/aharouni/data:/data/
    command: "jupyter lab /claraDevDay --ip 0.0.0.0 --allow-root --no-browser --config /claraDevDay/scripts/jupyter_notebook_config.py"
#    command: tail -f /dev/null
#    tty: true
    deploy:
      resources:
        reservations:
          devices:
            - driver: nvidia
              capabilities: [ gpu ]
              # To specify certain GPU uncomment line below
              #device_ids: ['0,3']
#############################################################
  tritonserver:
    image: nvcr.io/nvidia/tritonserver:21.02-py3
    container_name: aiaa-triton
    hostname: tritonserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: >
      sh -c "chmod 777 /triton_models &&
        /opt/tritonserver/bin/tritonserver \
          --model-store /triton_models \
          --model-control-mode="poll" \
          --repository-poll-secs=5 \
          --log-verbose ${TRITON_VERBOSE}"
    volumes:
      - ${TRAIN_DEV_DAY_ROOT}/AIAA/workspace/triton_models:/triton_models
#    shm_size: 1gb
#    ulimits:
#      memlock: -1
#      stack: 67108864
#    logging:
#      driver: json-file
```